# Chromadb not computing the embeddings with the correct model - wrong dimension

Tags: python, vector, langchain, embedding, chromadb

I have an issue with chromadb regarding the embeddings computation. I want to use a specific embeddings model: "ember-v1". So I load it by using the class sentence transformer from chromadb. I check the attributes of the instance and it is this model that is loaded.

However when I compute the embeddings, they have a dimension of 384 that does not corrrespond to the ember-v1 model. It should be 764. It is why I guet an error at the end of my code when I use this collection with langchain to query it.

```
import chromadb as db
from chromadb.utils import embedding_functions
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.embeddings import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings
from langchain.chat_models import AzureChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA
from rag.config import AzureChatOpenAIConfig

MODEL_NAME = "llmrails/ember-v1"
CLIENT_PATH_CHROMADB = "../db/"
COLLECTION_NAME = "Collection1"

# Embedding model setup
embedding_model = embedding_functions.SentenceTransformerEmbeddingFunction(model_name=MODEL_NAME)
chroma_client = db.PersistentClient(path=CLIENT_PATH_CHROMADB)
print(chroma_client.list_collections())

# Create or get the collection
collection_names = [collection.name for collection in chroma_client.list_collections()]
if COLLECTION_NAME not in collection_names:
    chroma_client.create_collection(
        name='Collection1',
        metadata={"hnsw:space": "cosine"},  # Specify space for embeddings
        embedding_function=embedding_model
    )

collection_one = chroma_client.get_collection(name=COLLECTION_NAME)

collection_one.add(
    ids=list_ids,
    documents=list_text,
    metadatas= list_metadatas
)


embeddings = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name=MODEL_NAME)

# Load the Chroma database from disk
chroma_db = Chroma(persist_directory=CLIENT_PATH_CHROMADB, 
                   embedding_function=embeddings,
                   collection_name=COLLECTION_NAME)



config = AzureChatOpenAIConfig.load_from_yaml(file_path="./openai_config.yml").dict()

llm = AzureChatOpenAI(**config)

# Prompt the model
chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm,
                                    chain_type="stuff",
                                    retriever=chroma_db.as_retriever())

# Execute the chain
response = chain(query)

# Print the response
print(response['result'])
```